# BeginAcceptTcpClient Holding.. doesn`t return function

Tags: c#, .net

Here is my C# source running on .NET Framework v4.5.2:

```
private void Accept(){
    Log("Start Accept");

    listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(new AsyncCallback(connection), null);

    Log("Finish Accept")
}

private void connection(IAsyncResult res){
   try{
       //
       //Check Disposed Logic
       //
    
       using (TcpClient tcpClient = _listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(res))
       {
           Accept();
           Stream stream = GetStream(tcpClient);
           ConnectionDetails connectionDetails = GetConnectionDetails(stream, tcpClient);
           using (IService service = _serviceFactory.CreateInstance(connectionDetails))
           {
              // do something
              service.Respond()
           }
       }
   }
}
```

"Finish Accept" log was not written and holding in `BeginAcceptTcpClient` function, but connection `AsyncCallback` works normally and connection is successful.

This situation occurs on average 1 out of 70 times, and it only appears when I reboot the computer.

When I simply run the program, it doesn't happen, even if I run it 500 times.

1. reboot and delay start program 1.30 minutes ~ 5 minutes
   -> this situation occurs on 1 out of 17 times
2. `AsyncCallback` function delay 5 seconds

I don't know why `BeginAcceptTcpClient` doesn't return

Comment: I want to know why BeginAcceptTcpClient doesn`t return intermittently 
and i want to fix it

Comment: avoid holding using Thread but this as a temporary measure .
still I don't know why BeginAcceptTcpClient doesn't return

Answer (score 0):

I guess you didn't terminate this connection, you need to call this function in your callback codes. **TcpListener.EndAcceptTcpClient(IAsyncResult)**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.endaccepttcpclient?view=net-7.0

Comment: More generally `BeginXXX` and `EndXXX` methods are APM style async, which has since been deprecated in favour for EAP async, which has also been deprecated in favour of TAP async. Please just use either the synchronous method, or the Task Async Programming methods instead.

Comment: @ReggieTan
sorry for the lack of explanation So i chaged my question code more detail
i already used EndAcceptTcpClient

Comment: @Aron It's not a new project So i can't chage TAP style right now

Comment: @ColdBrew Looking at your edit, it looks like it might be TCP socket exhaustion, caused by socket leaking, caused by bad resource management. Again, I recommend you use TAP to correctly write the `Accept` loop to correctly dispose the `Listener` on shutdown. Trying to correctly implement socket management with APM is going to produce some truly horrendous spaghetti code.

Comment: @ColdBrew There really shouldn't be ANY reason in 2023 that you aren't using TAP (short of targeting Win-7 dotnet 2/3.5). If it is an architectural reason, you can wrap up the Task using Rx.Net's `IDisposable TaskPoolScheduler.Default.Schedule(Func<IScheduler, CancellationToken, Task>)`.

Comment: @Aron I know that source code is spaghetti.
But what I'm curious about is that the TCP socket doesn't exhaustion until it's done several times?
In fact, it is not 1:N but 1:1 connection, but it is hold without returning from the BeginAcceptTcpClient function that is first tried.
this function is exported as a dll and other project loads this dll is not returned, so it is hold.
Of course, if you run it as a thread, the thread will be held and dll function finished, but it will go to the worst instead...